# When does the order of multiplication matter in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a program using dynamic programming and it took me quite a long time to find that something is wrong with the different versions of my code. It is as follows:

```
#the old version
if probs[i][k]*probs[k+1][j]*prob > tmp_prob:
    tmp_prob = prob*probs[i][k]*probs[k+1][j]

#the new version
res = probs[i][k]*probs[k+1][j]*prob
if res > tmp_prob:
    tmp_prob = res
```

I thought the results should be the same but, in fact, they are not. And

```
if probs[i][k]*probs[k+1][j]*prob > tmp_prob:
    tmp_prob = probs[i][k]*probs[k+1][j]*prob
```

and the result is the same as the new version. So I know the problem is that `probs[i][k]*probs[k+1][j]*prob` is not always equal to `prob*probs[i][k]*probs[k+1][j]`.

But when are they not equal? I think it is when there may be overflow, i.e., when `inf` occurs. But since  `probs[i][k]`, `probs[k+1][j]`, `prob` are all probabilities so they are all less than 1, so I don't think this is the case. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: You could compare both products and print the offending entries to get an idea of when they differ.

Comment: multiplication is commutative, the only way i can see you getting different values, is if you have very long floating point numbers

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: They could also "underflow" to zero.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, but the order doesn't matter because all the multiplier are probabilities so they are all less than 1.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, but if they are very small probabilities they can underflow to zero.

Comment: @BrenBarn They can underflow, but if in one order the underflow, in the other order it will underflow too. So the result should still be the same?

Comment: floating point multiplication is commutative, but not associative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow cannot happen here as you are using numbers between 0 and 1.
However, you have floating point errors. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

> On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision available for a Python float, so the value stored internally when you enter the decimal number 0.1 is the binary fraction

Here's a simple example to illustrate that with two numbers between 0 and 1:

```
>>> a = 0.141421356237309515
>>> b = 0.519787654313216655
>>> a*a*b - a*b*a
1.734723475976807e-18
```

If that's an issue for what you want to do, you can use fixed point arithmetic. Have a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 2):

With floating point values, you may see slight differences by changing the order of the multiplications, although I would normally expect the difference to be very small (relative to the magnitude of the value), unless an intermediate result overflows or underflows, but I would expect those cases to be more obvious.

Here's a simple example:

```
>>> import math
>>> t = math.sqrt(3.0)
>>> 3*t*t
9.0
>>> t*t*3
8.999999999999998
>>> 3*t*t - t*t*3
1.7763568394002505e-15
>>>
```

Mathematically, both products should be `9.0` and their difference should be `0.0`, but due to floating point roundoff, that is not the case.  The actual results may differ from one platform to another, but this is what I get on my computer, and it illustrates one of the difficulties with floating point arithmetic.